# neo4j-import failing on Prepare node index phase

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to import 130M nodes  and 200M relationships on a new neo4j database from csv files using neo4-import tool and it gets stuck on the process.

The output of the process:

```
Nodes [>:3.35 MB/s---|PROPERTIES(2)======|*NODE:1007.08 MB------|LABEL SCAN-----|v:7.46 MB/s(2)======]131M
Done in 1h 35m 47s 332ms
Prepare node index
[*SORT:1.47 GB---------------------------------------------------------------------------------] 87M
```

The content of messages.log

```
2015-06-15 10:38:56.423+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: Import starting
2015-06-15 10:38:56.537+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: Creating new db @ /var/user/neo/graph22.db/neostore
2015-06-15 10:38:57.264+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: Missing counts store, rebuilding it.
2015-06-15 10:38:57.536+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: No lucene scan store index found, this might just be first use. Preparing to rebuild.
2015-06-15 10:38:57.581+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: No lucene scan store index found, this might just be first use. Preparing to rebuild.
2015-06-15 10:38:57.793+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: Rebuilding lucene scan store, this may take a while
2015-06-15 10:38:57.796+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: Lucene scan store rebuilt (roughly -1 nodes)
2015-06-15 18:29:33.509+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: About to rotate counts store at transaction 1 to [/var/user/neo/graph22.db/neostore.counts.db.b], from [/var/user/neo/graph22.db/neostore.counts.db.a].
2015-06-15 18:29:33.516+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: Successfully rotated counts store at transaction 1 to [/var/user/neo/graph22.db/neostore.counts.db.b], from [/var/user/neo/graph22.db/neostore.counts.db.a].
2015-06-15 18:29:33.771+0000 ERROR [org.neo4j]: Error during import null
java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.ParallelSort.partition(ParallelSort.java:193)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.ParallelSort.recursiveQsort(ParallelSort.java:243)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.ParallelSort.recursiveQsort(ParallelSort.java:246)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.ParallelSort.recursiveQsort(ParallelSort.java:246)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.ParallelSort.recursiveQsort(ParallelSort.java:246)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.ParallelSort.recursiveQsort(ParallelSort.java:246)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.ParallelSort.recursiveQsort(ParallelSort.java:246)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.ParallelSort.recursiveQsort(ParallelSort.java:246)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.ParallelSort.recursiveQsort(ParallelSort.java:246)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.ParallelSort.recursiveQsort(ParallelSort.java:246)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.ParallelSort.recursiveQsort(ParallelSort.java:246)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.ParallelSort.recursiveQsort(ParallelSort.java:246)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.ParallelSort.recursiveQsort(ParallelSort.java:246)
```

What's causing the process to fail? Is there anything i can do in order to solve this?

I'm using neo4j-community-2.2.2

Comment: Which 2.2.x version are you using?

Comment: I'm using neo4j-community-2.2.2

Comment: How does your node IDs look generally and which --id-type are you using?

Comment: Default value for --id-type (STRING). The node IDs are base64 encoded Strings without equals '=' and new line characters '\n'. Some of them may contain underline chars '_'

Comment: Have you tried running the import again? Is this error reproducible?

Comment: Yes, It always gets stuck on
`[*SORT:1.47 GB---------------------------------------------------------------------------------] 87M`

Comment: I'm having the same issue, trying to import a 75M file

Comment: Strange that it's so consistent since there's an element of randomness in the sorting algorithm. See https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/pull/4877 for a probable improvement though. Also getting access to the raw data would be terribly helpful in debugging this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't share the data with you because it is sensitive. I am testing the importer with a subset of the data and so far it is working properly.  could it be related to the size of the data?

Comment: It probably is. You mentioned it gets stuck, is it actually getting stuck or fails with the StackOverflowError. Do both happened randomly there? How long have you waited?

Comment: It gets stuck for hours (87M on 'Prepare node index') and then it fails with the StackOverflowError. Is there anything I can check in order to ensure that is a size related problem?

Comment: There's a PR to change the implementation to an iterative qsort instead to avoid stackoverflow, https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/pull/4877 . That should improve things for you.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but with the version 2.2.3. I kind of solved it by editing the file bin/neo4j-import and adding more stack space (and more heap as well, just because i have it):

```
EXTRA_JVM_ARGUMENTS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xmx8g -Xss128m"
```

But now I have a different problem - recursion is 1023 levels deep (and I am only sorting around 500 million nodes), and I am not sure if the sort will ever finish :)